# Is it enough to copy grub.cfg

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, fat32

I have installed Windows 10 in the first half of my HDD. Then I install Ubuntu in the second half (minus 1GB). After all I formatted third 1GB partition in FAT32 then I install grub into it using `grub-install --boot-directory /mnt/boot /dev/sda`. `/mnt/boot/` is mount point for 1GB partition itself. After reboot I have only `grub>` command line prompt.

I want to replace grub, installed along with Ubuntu with new grub installed in separate partition. Is it enough to just copy grub.cfg from `/boot/` to `/mnt/boot/`?

Comment: Why do you want there to be a 3rd partition? Is it a separate /boot partition or a "share"? Did you format it AFTER the install? What exactly do you get in grub, isn't it 'grub rescue>'?

Comment: @KryštofPíštěk I want to get access from windows to grub.cfg. It is separate /boot partition. I format it using mkdosfs -F 32

Comment: @KryštofPíštěk It was just `grub>`. I think there just no `menuentry` for either Windows on /dev/sda1 or Ubuntu on /dev/sda4.

Comment: I don't know how to add that entries.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have installed the OS and THEN made the boot partition. You can take 2 routes to fix this problem, as far as I know.
a) Repair the install
This is the harder route, and needs you to:
1) Boot into the install CD/DVD
2) Mount the partition with / somewhere (let's say /mnt) and rename the /mnt/boot folder to something else, like boot.old (modify accordingly if not using /mnt)
3) Create a blank /mnt/boot folder and mount the new separate /boot partition into there
4) Copy all files from the old /boot folder into the new /boot partition (files inside /mnt/boot.old into /mnt/boot, but be careful to keep the directory layout)
5) Adjust the /mnt/etc/fstab to include the new /boot partition
6) Bind mount (sudo mount --bind  ) the /dev, /proc, /sys into /mnt/
7) Chroot into the /mnt folder (sudo chroot /mnt) and run the grub-install command you ran earlier. Also run update-grub.
8) Exit out of the chroot, unmout everything you've mounted and try to reboot. 
b) Reinstall
Obviously the easy route. You would need to:
1) Start the Ubuntu installation from the CD/DVD
2) Continue as you did, but:
3) Choose something else at the partitioning scheme, choose the Ubuntu partition and select / for the mount point, then choose your fat32 /boot partition and choose /boot as the mountpoint.
4) Continue with the install.

To answer your question, no, copying grub.cfg is not enough.